# Is there an immersion which is not a closed immersion composited with an open immersion?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $f:Z\to X$ be a morphism of schemes which can be factorized as $Z\to U\to X$ such that $Z\to U$ is an open immersion and $U\to X$ is a closed immersion. It's easy to show $f$ is an immersion.

Please give an example that an immersion $Z\to X$ can't be factorized as $Z\to U\to X$ such that $Z\to U$ is an open immersion and $U\to X$ is a closed immersion.

Comment: See http://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/01QW

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez: How odd, is this because the ring in the example is non-noetherian? There is Exercise 3.2.3 in Qing Lius's book which states that such a factorization is always possible. I recall that it was so obvious in the classical setting, I didn't really ponder on it a whole lot.

Comment: @JeskoHüttenhain $X$ being noetherian would suffice, since [morphisms to (locally) noetherian schemes are quasi-compact](http://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/01OX), and quasi-compact immersions [can be factored as an open immersion followed by a closed immersion](http://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/01QV). It also suffices to just have [$Z$ noetherian](http://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/01P0), or [$Z$ reduced](http://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/03DQ). The issue with non-quasi-compactness is that scheme-theoretic closures don't work well: the relevant sheaf of ideals may not be quasi-coherent.

Comment: @TakumiMurayama, thanks a lot!